# Fixing my implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++

Tags: c++, primes

My algorithm runs correctly up to the first 100 primes but then something goes wrong. Please have a look at my code below, I tried to follow the pseudo-code given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n = 1000; //compute primes up to this number
  vector<bool> p(true,n); //all values set to true, from 0 to n

  for(int i = 2; i < sqrt(n)+1; i++){
    if( p[i-1] == true ){
      for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i) //start looking for multiples of prime i at i*i (optimized)
    p[j-1] = false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    if( p[i-1] == true )
      cout << i << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
193
199
```

Comment: "My algorithm runs correctly up to the first 100 primes". No it doesn't. It fails after having correctly identified 61.

Comment: @miro Optimizing does not mean debugging and fixing the errors.

Comment: On a side note, `i < sqrt(n)+1` means you are calculating the square root on every iteration. Probably better to calculate it above the loop and store it in a variable.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is optimized for size, avoid it if you want speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm absolutely amazed the program runs at all. It has an absolute **truckload** of **undefined behaviour**!.

Unless I'm very much mistaken (in which case please reward the serenity of my Friday afternoon with downvotes), `vector<bool> p(true, n)` is creating a vector of size `true`, with the elements initialised to `n`.

You have the constructor arguments the wrong way round. This is effectively reversing the sieve for most of the values.

Have you absolutely clobbered your compiler's warning level?

Comment: You do are right [`std::vector::vector(size_type, const T&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Yes I just noticed, but it still ran despite that...my compiler is not the best I suppose, I am using gcc version 4.8.3, also how is it even possible to create a vector of size "true"? Because true can be any non-negative value. Is the size set as 1 in that case as default?

Comment: It's not your compiler whom is to be blamed; it's your code.

Comment: Is it possible to set some flags when compiling to tell me I have undefined behavior?

Comment: Since you don't explicitly resize the vector, your almost always writing outside its bounds. I can only assume that your very nice runtime library is somehow allocating all the memory you need with some curious capacity setting.

Comment: @miro normally compile with `-Wall -pedantic`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not need to store a boolean value for each and every number. This way, you are wasting memory. You should store only the found primes instead, unless you have a very good reason not to do so.

I will not implement the code, since it would spoil the joy of learning. You should implement the following:

- Initialize `p` as a vector of integers.
- Store 2 as first value inside `p`
- Iterate all odd numbers starting from 3 and ending at the end number
- For each number, calculate its square root and store it into a variable
- Iterate all previous elements of the `p` until you reach a divisor or the value of the vector at the given index reaches the square root, starting from the second element, as pair numbers larger than 2 are ignored
- If you find a divisor inside your inner loop, store it into your vector and get out of the inner loop

At the end you will have a `vector` of primes, indexes will mean the prime index and the values will be actual primes. Each element will be a prime of its own.

Comment: Its no longer the algorithm "Sieve of Eratosthenes" if he does that. It still works, but so does SoE.

Comment: It is true that my solution is no longer the same as the original Sieve of Erathosthenes, but it is in the spirit of the algorithm, so I would not say that this is different. It is an optimized version, which fulfilled the answer to the initial criteria. So, @sp2danny, I agree with your comment, but I still believe this is a valid answer, since the initial question title was "Optimizing my implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++".

Answer (score 0):

You mess your numbering up. If `p[k]` is the primeness of number `k+1`, your for loop is wrong

```
for(int j = i*i; j < n; j += i)
```

and should be

```
for(int j = (i-1)*(i-1); j < n; j += (i-1))
```

My advice would be to use more informative variable names and avoid those sources of confusion like `p[k]` giving information about integer `k+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector construction is wrong. It must be

```
vector<bool> p(n, true); //all values set to true, from 0 to n
```

instead of

```
vector<bool> p(true, n); //all values set to true, from 0 to n
```

Comment: Yes that seemed to have been the problem thank you for that, silly mistake